# My regex does not match yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss

Tags: regex, datetime, iso8601

I have tried

```
^(19|20)\d\d[-](0[1-9]|1[012])[-](0[1-9]|12[0-9]|3[01]T(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0123]):(0[0-9]|12345[0-9]):(0[0-9]|12345[0-9]))$
```

and

```
^(19|20)\d\d[-](0[1-9]|1[012])[-](0[1-9]|12[0-9]|3[01][T](0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0123])[:](0[0-9]|12345[0-9])[:](0[0-9]|12345[0-9]))$
```

and neither of them worked on a sample datetime - 2009-06-15T13:45:30

Comment: Are you using VB.NET? You could split strings with space and use `DateTime.TryParse()` to obtain all datetime values.

Comment: DateTime.TryParse would not work. For example DateTime.TryParse("376 7",CDate(strTemp)) will return true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have missed a parenthesis and add an extra one at the end:

```
^(19|20)\d\d[-](0[1-9]|1[012])[-](0[1-9]|[[12][0-9]|3[01])T(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0123]??):(0[0-9]|[12345][0-9]):(0[0-9]|[12345][0-9])$ 
//                          add parenthesis here       __^                                           and delete the one here __^
```

You may also simplify to:

```
^(19|20)\d\d-(0[1-9]|1[012])-([012]\d|3[01])T([01]\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d):([0-5]\d)$
```

Another way to go to test only the format then test the validity is:

```
^(\d{4})-(\d\d)-(\d\d)T(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)$
```

and then test the validity:

- group1 between 1900 and 2000
- group2 between 01 and 12
- group3 between 01 and 31
- group4 between 00 and 23
- group5 between 00 and 59
- group6 between 00 and 59

Or, better, use a date parser;, I'm there is one that exists in your favorite language.

Answer (score 1):

Toto's answer fixes all your problems but doesn't tell you why.

You have 4 mistakes:

1. wrongly placed parenthesis

   `(0[1-9]|12[0-9]|3[01]T -> (0[1-9]|12[0-9]|3[01])T`
2. lack of brackets on hours first digit

   `(0[1-9]|12[0-9]|3[01]) -> (0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])`
3. lack of brackets on seconds first digit

   `(0[0-9]|12345[0-9]) -> (0[0-9]|[12345][0-9])`
4. Missplaced parenthesis at the end

   `(0[0-9]|12345[0-9]))$ -> (0[0-9]|12345[0-9])$`

For the optimization of this, I will quote Toto's answer.

```
^(19|20)\d\d-(0[1-9]|1[012])-([012]\d|3[01])T([01]\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d):([0-5]\d)$
```

this is your second solution before the fixes:

```
^(19|20)\d\d[-](0[1-9]|1[012])[-](0[1-9]|12[0-9]|3[01][T](0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0123])[:](0[0-9]|12345[0-9])[:](0[0-9]|12345[0-9]))$
```

[image]

this is your second solution after the fixes:

```
^(19|20)\d\d[-](0[1-9]|1[012])[-](0[1-9]|[1]2[0-9]|3[01])[T](0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0123])[:](0[0-9]|12345[0-9])[:](0[0-9]|[12345][0-9])$
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is my working recipe

```
const exp  = /^([\+-]?\d{4}(?!\d{2}\b))((-?)((0[1-9]|1[0-2])(\3([12]\d|0[1-9]|3[01]))?|W([0-4]\d|5[0-2])(-?[1-7])?|(00[1-9]|0[1-9]\d|[12]\d{2}|3([0-5]\d|6[1-6])))([T\s]((([01]\d|2[0-3])((:?)[0-5]\d)?|24\:?00)([\.,]\d+(?!:))?)?(\17[0-5]\d([\.,]\d+)?)?([zZ]|([\+-])([01]\d|2[0-3]):?([0-5]\d)?)?)?)?$/g;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have for the day part 12[0-9] which is the problem. Probably mean [12][0-9]

Comment: Sami, I have the same issue as with date with minutes and seconds so I changed my code to ^(19|20)\d\d[-](0[1-9]|1[012])[-](0[1-9]|[[12][0-9]|3[01]T(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0123]):(0[0-9]|[12345][0-9]):(0[0-9]|[12345][0-9]))$  but still no match found